# Downloading large files over 300mb and more frontend/backend

Tags: javascript, file, download

Downloading files in base64 encoding. Browser (Chrome) handle very long time request from server in my front-end. My handler of data from server:

```
downloadFile(file: Blob, fileName: string = '') {

    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);


    downloadLink.href = objectUrl;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.target = '_self';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
}
```

Code from server (it's just example, original data is so large for paste here):

[image]

It's works for small files < 5mb. But I get large file over > 300mb and it crash browser.

I need another solution for resolve this problem. Maybe I need another way to realize it for backend/frontend

Comment: Why not send the file-blob directly?

Comment: Sending a large file in Base64 would be very inefficient, get the server end to send it in Binary.

Comment: In this situation Blob file helps me. I rewrite my handler a little and Chrome tabs stops freezing and crash. Guys in comments, THANKS A LOT! Now I can download files more 1 gb too, and this ok. Server gets me binary file